# jQuery: Prevent Default before Submit (extra functionality), but after successful Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Before submitting the form, I need to do some extra functionality (dynamically add Hidden Fields to the form).

But I'm also using jQuery Validate. How do I ensure that the below code executes after successful jQuery Validate (no errors), but before actual Submit?

I don't want to add this custom handler directly in the jQuery Validate block. The Submit functionality is not really related to validation code.

```
 // This handler should only be invoked after jQuery Validate successfully
 // completes with no errors, otherwise it should never get here
 $('#submitButton').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     myExtraCode();
     $('#formId').submit();
 });
```

Comment: If you're instantiating jQuery validate on the `form` element (which you should be), then the form submission will happen by default. You don't need to add any additional click handlers. If you want to run some custom logic when the form is submit, use jQuery validate's `submitHandler` property

Comment: Are you sure? I would think the click method is always triggered no matter what but I can check...

Comment: It would help to see how you've setup jQuery validate and a sample of the form HTML, if relevant

Comment: What Rory just tried telling you!  If you're using jQuery Validate, then [anything you put inside this plugin's `submitHandler` happens *after* a valid form but *before* the submission.  That's the whole point of this handler.](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler)  Your custom click handler is completely unnecessary and will likely interfere with the plugin.  You also have a very poorly constructed question where you've left out nearly all of the relevant code; the call to `.validate()` and the HTML of the form?

Comment: Sparky, that's the issue. I don't want to use jQuery Validate's submitHandler(). It forces me to put unrelated code inside a Validation block, which in my case is complex. It would be easier if I could do outside the Validation block `if $('#form').valid()) { ... } ` in my custom button handler. Can I do that?

Comment: Yes, you could do that.  Change the submit button into a `type="button"`, which prevents submission.  Then use a `click` handler on this `button`.  Then put your `if  .valid()...` conditional inside of that.  At the end you can trigger a `.submit()` which turns it back over to the plugin to finish the submit.